# Difference between "Single Line" and "Multi Line Submit" in unity text mesh pro

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the difference between "Single Line" and "Multi Line Submit" in unity text mesh pro?
Both of them call OnEndEdit Event when pressing Enter keyboard button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is basically an extension of the `UI.InputField` so I would expect the same behavior as for a normal input field where you can find the option as [`UI.InputField.LineType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.LineType.html)

> **`SingleLine`**
>   
> Only allows 1 line to be entered. Has horizontal scrolling and no word wrap. Pressing enter will submit the `InputField`.
>
> **`MultiLineSubmit`**
>   
> Is a multiline `InputField` with vertical scrolling and overflow. Pressing the return key will submit.
>
> **`MultiLineNewline`**
>   
> Is a multiline `InputField` with vertical scrolling and overflow. Pressing the return key will insert a new line character.

---

[here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/only-make-new-line-when-shift-enter-is-pressed.514534/) someone implemented a script to be able to type new lines using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when using the `MultiLineSubmit` option.